# How to access a child window inside a main window in White Framework

Tags: c#, windows, ui-automation, white-framework

I am using White framework to do UI automation in a Windows desktop based application. I am not able to find a way to access a child window. UIAVerify depicts the properties of the window as:

[image]

Below is the code for reference:

```
public class Program
{
    Application app = Application.Launch("Path to my application");

    public Program()
    {
        //Getting the main window
        Window MainWindow = app.GetWindow("MainForm", InitializeOption.NoCache);
        MainWindow.WaitWhileBusy();
        **//Here I wanna get the child window so that I can access controls on that window. Below is the code for getting child windows controls** 
        //Getting to the Firm box
        TextBox firm = Childwindow.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("1313948"));
        //setting value for firm
        firm.SetValue("FIRM2");
        //getting StaffID text box
        TextBox StaffID = Childwindow.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("723272"));
        StaffID.SetValue("Staff");

        Button Ok = Childwindow.Get <Button>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("_okB[enter image description here][1]utton"));
        Ok.Click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TreeScope.Children to access the immediate child elements of the desktop:

```
AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.RootElement;
    var winCollection = rootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);

    foreach (AutomationElement element in winCollection)
        Console.WriteLine(element.Current.Name);
```